# Passing a list of lists into tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wanted to know how to pass in a list of lists into a tensor in tensorflow. I was able to pass in arrays of [batch_size, seq_len] in where each item is just a number. But now I have a list of lists also of shape (batch_size, seq_len] but how do I pass this in?

I tried this:

```
self.inputs_X = [tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, None],
                 name='inputs_X{0}'.format(i)) for i in xrange(SEQ_LEN)]
```

(* any way I can do this without explicitly passing in SEQ_LEN ?)

First of all the tf.int32, doesn't make sense because i'm not longer passing in an int, im passsing in a list. And so, I'm getting this error:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow's equivalent to a "list of x" is to increase the dimension of an existing tensor.

e.g. If you were passing in a list of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and you now want to pass in a list of these, you increase the dimensionality by 1 and end up with a matrix (aka a tensor of dimension 2).

`tf.int32` still makes sense as your tensor still contains entirely ints.

It's hard to tell but I think you can simply add an extra element to your shape parameter, e.g. `tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, None, SEQ_LEN])` (replacing SEQ_LEN with None if appropriate). I haven't seen the data, so SEQ_LEN may need to be in a different position too.

Another strategy is to flatten your list-of-lists into a single list and then use `tf.reshape` to change it into the matrix or higher-dimensional shape you need.

Comment: Ok so I decided to go with shape=[None, None, None] which works nicely!
  But I've been trying to wrestle with my task in this form but I'm not able to figure it out. Let's say that I embedded my inputs and now I have it at shape [64 X 41 X 395 X 500]. This is 64 (batch_size), 41 (seq_len), 395 (events in each item), 500 (embeddings to represent each event).

Comment: The result I am trying to create is [64 X 41 X 500] and what this means is for each case in the minibatch, I will still have all 41 items but for each item I will have a 500 float embedding representing. We reduce to just 500 because I will take the 395 X 500 for each item, compute the average. Now here's the tricky part, for each single case (row), I have lengths which is a tensor that looks like this, where each row is of size 41:
    [9 0 0 0 ... 0 0]
    [9 8 0 0 ... 0 0]
    ...

Comment: So for the first single case from my minibatch, 9 means take the first 9 items from 395 and average them.
    So this creates a 1X41X500 where only the 1st column has any values, rest are zero.
    Then for second case from my minibatch, [9, 8, 0, ... 0] means take the first 9 items from 1st/41 395 and average them.

Comment: Then take 8 items from the 2nd/41 395 and average them. So this creates a 1X41X500, where the first and second columns have values but rest have zeroes. Background: I'm trying to implement the youtube recommendation paper and this is the first time I'm dealing with embedding list of lists like this. I tried playing with tf.gather(), tf.reshape() but I'm not able to figure it out.